# how to log to googleads requests?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, google-ads-api

We've followed the advice given here:
https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/client-libs/java/logging

Neither of the proposed solutions have any visible effect on what is logged to the console, either in dev or in deployment.

Specifically:

- added to pom.xml:

  ```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
  ```
- added -Dlog4j.configuration=googleads-logging/log4j.properties to the launch command

no effect.

- added to pom.xml:

  ```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
  ```
- created jdk-logger.properties in various places, from example found [here](https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-java/tree/master/google-ads/src/main/resources/googleads-logging)
- added -Djava.util.logging.config.file= to the launch command

no effect whatsoever.

We are desperately trying to sort out [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64269197/google-ads-api-no-response-from-server-after-migrating-to-9-0) before Google sunsets the googleads v2 API on October 21. It would be really nice to see exactly what is happening, but so far all we've managed to determine is the endpoint server: googleads.googleapis.com:443

Any advice highly appreciated!